# What is "The Dark" and where can I learn more about it?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force

I was reading about the concept of "The Dark" in *Luke Skywalker and the Shadows of Mindor* and I want to learn more about it.
It isn't on [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Main_Page) (surprisingly) and not on the [CUSWE](http://www.theforce.net/) (Complete Unofficial Star Wars Encyclopedia). However some articles there touch up upon it.

Can anybody explain The Dark in detail to me or direct me to an online Star Wars encyclopaedia with an entry on it?

Comment: **It isnt on Wookieepedia (suprisingly)** Searching for "The Dark" on Wookieepedia brings up the [Way of the Dark](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Way_of_the_Dark) entry as its first result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong place on Wookieepedia. All the views of the Force are listed, unsurprisinging, on "The Force" page. If you search that page for "Mindor" you get to a reference, and tracing back that reference gets you:

https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Force#Way_of_the_Dark (which, in turn, links to the main article, [Way of the Dark](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Way_of_the_Dark)

> The Way of the Dark, or simply the Dark, was a view of the Force taken up by Cronal and those that taught him. It was effectively the polar opposite of the [Potentium](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Potentium), but taken a step further. This Way of the Dark belief did not just deny the existence of the Light side of the Force; it stated that the Force itself was simply a small extension of the Dark. This system stated that destruction was the universal constant that all things worked towards, going so far as to call it the "will of the universe". An initiate was taught that if one made destruction his primary goal, with whatever scheme he was taking part in being a secondary objective, then the Dark would effectively reward the initiate for the devastation caused by pushing the secondary objective to success.
>
> As a prime example of this, Cronal cited that Palpatine was able to achieve success against the Jedi and the Republic because his primary motive was the destruction of both parties. However, once he had achieved these goals and set about consolidating his rule and building the Empire, his focus shifted from destruction to creation, in total opposition to universal processes. Thus when before he could not fail, now he could never succeed

Comment: Oddly enough, the universal process of entropy kind of fits that description, although it certainly doesn't offer rewards to those who accelerate it, unless you count the usage of energy.